# How to get the Hive source sql from Yarn?

Tags: sql, hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

My hive is running on MapReduce and Yarn. I find that the name of the yarn application is just a SQL fragment, but what want is the source SQL from yarn web ui or Yarn restapi.

[image]

What can I do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to see the Hive query:

1. Click on the Application ID link. It will open a page with the application details.
2. There will be a link called "Tracking URL". Click on that.
3. It would open the DAG and you will find the Hive query in that.